# OSX Xcode fails to download additional iOS Simulators from preferences->download

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am an inexperienced iOS developer, have just bought a macbook and installed xcode 4.6
I went to Xcode->preferences->downloads->components to download additional simulators
I see 4 choices:
1) command line tools
2) iOS 5.0 Simulator (around 600 MB)
3) iOS 5.1 Simulator (around 600 MB)
4) iOS 6.0 Simulator (around 600 MB)

I press Install for iOS 5.0 Simulator and it shows me a progress bar. however, the progress bar moves very slowly (around 20% of completion in 3 hours) and then it breaks after some 4 hours since download start with a message "network connection was lost".

I have a fast connection of more than 20 Mbit/sec and can download files of the size of 600MB in no time. 
I thought this could be some kind of a problem with my particular ISP so I tried repeating this from 4 distinct different places with different ISPs (the speed was always like 20 Mbit or more).

the result was the same - it downloads roughly 20-25% in 3 hours and breaks.
This is real slow for a 20 Mbit connection on a 600 file.

so its not ISP
I dont expect this to be a problem with my particular Mac either because it downloads other files from other websites with a normal expected speed of my internet connection.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be? some setting in Xcode like "limit download speed to 3600 baud" ?

Extra Info:

OSX Version: 10.8
Xcode version: 4.6
Mac type: MacBook Air

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?  I'm able to install and download all 4 available simulators.  This seems weird.

Comment: as far as i know there are no restrictions on the size of the download unless its set by the internet provider. i had the same issue with downloading other simulators on my mac also. i never found out what it was but after a few time that i tried it just got through. so that may just be what you need to do. try it again. i know it does not sound like an answer but i thought of sharing it with you.

Comment: thanks. I tried a total of 20 times with around 10 complete poweroffs in between and 4 ISPs, been doing that for 2 weeks occasionnally now and then...  seems really strange - download speed seem to be like 3600 baud

Comment: Stan Cromlish, how long does an install take normally? I guess its like 10 minutes to download and 10 to install, at maximum. should be event faster.  It should not download at 3600 baud, correct?

Comment: Is there any place for an alternative download, if it fails again?  trying to download right now

Comment: just in case:stackoverflow.com/questions/15577361/alternative-download-for-ios-6-simulator/

Comment: It took my download/install about 5 minutes to complete.  So it could be a problem with your XCode install.

Comment: I tried 3 more times and was able to finally download all three packages. a total of 1.5GB took 3 hours to complete, I agree that this is some problem (must be), because such download speeds are more 1999 than 2013.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem: progress bar seems freeze/very slow, following by connection lost error 10-15 minutes afterwards (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199446/download-ios-7-simulator-on-xcode-6).

Comment: The similar question I posted earlier is somehow deleted by Admin :( , hence I'm posting my progress here. I just wiped off my hard disk and did a clean installation of Yosemite, following by Xcode 6.2 installation, now I'm no more facing the problem to download simulator. Root cause is still unclear but at least now it is gone for me after those tedious work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 3 more times and was able to finally download all three packages. a total of 1.5GB took 3 hours to complete. So, this is some unresolved problem, because such download speeds are really uncommon for my 20+ Mbit connections.

Anyway, the problem with "can not install" is resolved.
the problem with download speed remains.

Thanks to all the commenters for ideas and support.